# How will you know if your node is synced post Coordinator removal?

Tags: node, coordinator, syncing

Currently node sync status is determined by milestones which are issued by the coordinator. Once autosnapshots, and removal of the coordinator occurs, how will we know if the node is in sync with the rest of the network?

Comment: I really like the question but unfortunately there is no answer, yet. Every answer will be opinion-based and speculative. IOTA is a researched focussed project and the answer to your question still has to be researched.

Comment: The question will remain. It will be reopened and answered as soon as it is possible to answer it.

Comment: IMO, the real question is : "What means 'synced node' when there is no COO ?"